# Microsoft's StreamInsight - Experiences & SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, complex-event-processing, streaminsight

Microsoft's Complex Event Processing (CEP) offering [StreamInsight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362541%28SQL.105%29.aspx) was released in tandem with SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am wondering:

- if StreamInsight is in any way tied
  to the SQL Server 2008 R2 database and
  if it can be run separately.

  *(From scanning over the documentation 
     it looks like StreamInsight can be

     run separately but clarification would be desirable).*
- If you have experience using StreamInsight separate from SQL Server 2008 R2 how has the experience been?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As for your thoughts regarding StreamInsight (SI) and SQL Server 2008 R2; at least at this moment, SI has no dependencies on SQL Server 2008 R2 what so ever. For certain operations you may need a SQL Server Compact (CE) db, which stores metadata – but you can definitely use SI against other databases than SQL if you so wish." Niels of http://www.sqldevelop.com/

Answer (score 2):

Responding to Tom's issues ...

> Lacks query code reuse options

How so? First, you have Query Templates, which allow for query code reuse right out of the box. Second, you can create an architecture (as we have) that encapsulates related sets of queries in a provider model and then hook them up to various input and output adapters.

> Adapters are constrained to pulling rather than pushing

Again, how so? The input adapters push data into the StreamInsight engine. Whether or not the data gets pushed into the input adapter depends on the source. We've created an OPC-DA input adapter that uses subscriptions and has data pushed from OPC. OSISoft's PI adapter works the same way.

> No fail-over mechanism, no persistency guaranteed.

That is true.

> Window logic is not as straightforward as other engines

That may be your opinion based on what you've used before and what you are familiar with. I've found StreamInsight's model to be relatively straightforward, flexible and powerful. I also find the query language (LINQ) much easier to use and very natural for a C# developer.

On another note, most of the other CEP engines out there are a very "heavy" install and can have a significant impact on an enterprise architecture - this from someone that's seen several installations of TIBCO do very unpleasant things to a network. StreamInsight is very lightweight and has a very small footprint compared to other engines.
Just my $.02 worth.

Answer (score 1):

StreamInsight have some limitations in the event types, he accept simple (very simple) variable types. In case of an OPC server it is useless ...

Comment: Can you please explain your use case, where StreamInsight types are not sufficient? The majority of OPC applications use OPC-DA, where the most typical data types (based on VARIANTs) will be VT_I2, VT_UI2, VT_R4 and such, fairly simple stuff. More complex data types can be used e.g. in OPC UA, but yet again not so often in my view. We have created a product that brings [OPC data into StreamInsight](http://www.opclabs.com/products/streaminsight-option), and have not had this kind of complaint yet.

Answer (score -2):

my experience with streaminsight has been in a POC we've made here.
this product is not mature enough in my opinion to be a production infrastructure.

Comment: Can you add any specifics re: the maturity?

Comment: yes i can, but it will be based on the CTP 3 version - since i haven't worked with last RTM version. 
This product might be good for simple scenarios, and some simple aggregations. it lucks query code reuse options, it lucks testing features,  Adapters are constrained to pulling rather them pushing, no fail-over mechanism, no persistency guaranteed, windows logic is not as straight forward as in other engines.
if you try the free trial version of coral8 you will understand the difference in product maturity.